# onPress function firing on page load

Tags: react-native

**Background**

In my React Native application I am passing a component which renders a button with an onPress function. When this button is pressed it should take the user to a web page to view some information. Instead of the button working when it is clicked it is firing off and taking the user to the web page without being clicked. I am unsure why this is happening and would like some insight.

**Example**

This is where the button originates from.

*Button Component*

```
class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress()} style={styles.cardButtonWrap}>
          <Text style={styles.cardButton}>Button</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

*AlbumDetail*

This is where the Button component is called.

```
class AlbumDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
<Button onPress={() => Linking.openURL(this.props.album.url)} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you should use {()=> {this.props.onPress()}} instead of {this.props.onPress()}

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: No problem, Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function inside of onPress. Use this code instead:

```
class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress} style={styles.cardButtonWrap}>
          <Text style={styles.cardButton}>Button</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```